# Rails 5 edit multiple not showing values in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating multiple edit on my app. I have followed the revised Rails screencast and [this](https://github.com/bparanj/emu/tree/master/app) code that adapts it to Rails 5.

In my Categories Controller:

```
def edit_multiple
    @categories = Category.where(ID: params[:category_ids])
    redirect_to categories_url
end
```

In my index:

```
   <table class="table" summary="Category list">

     <tr class="header">
       <th style="text-align: left"><%= sort_link(@q, :NAME, 'NAME', default_order: :desc) %></th>
       <th style="text-align: left">POSITION</th>
       <th style="text-align: left">ACTIONS</th>
      </tr>
        <%= render "list" %>
   </table>

   <%= submit_tag "Edit Checked" %>
```

In my list partial:

```
<% form_tag edit_multiple_categories_path, method: :get do %>

      <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <tr class="<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">
        <td><%= check_box_tag "category_ids[]", category.ID %></td>
        <td><%=  link_to category.NAME, {:action => 'show', :ID => category.ID} %>
        <td><%= category.RANK_POSITION %></td>
        <td class="actions">
          <%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit', :ID => category.ID}, :class => 'button tiny') %>
          <%= link_to("Delete", {:action => 'delete', :ID => category.ID}, :class => 'alert button tiny') %>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

When I open the categories page, it doesn't show anything from _list partial. There's only table headers and Edit Checked button.

Before adding the code relative to multiple edits the table was showing values from partial.

Note that db column names are capital as I'm building the app on existing db.

How can I fix it?

Comment: When you redirect from `edit_multiple` to `index`, the instance variable `@categories` loses its value, because you start a new request.

Comment: thanks for the input. but how do i fix it then?

Comment: i dont think that's the problem, @categories.size shows correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simply that

```
<% form_tag edit_multiple_categories_path, method: :get do %>
```

should be:

```
<%= form_tag edit_multiple_categories_path, method: :get do %>
```

I copied that from the railscast [#165](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple?view=asciicast)

Perhaps someone will find same issue and will find this useful.